# Why do I get a wrong result from SeriesCoefficient?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 13.3**

---

Consider the following code:

```
func[x_] = Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3);
c[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[func[x], {x, 0, n}]
```

> `Piecewise[{{((I/2)*3^(1 + n)*(-1 + E^((2*I)/27)))/E^(I/27), n >= 0}}, 0]`

That looks at least suspicious. Substituting `n = 0` yields a nonzero result:

```
c[0] // FullSimplify
```

> `-3 Sin[1/27]`

But the function is zero at `x == 0`; moreover, `Series` agrees with me:

```
Normal @ Series[func[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

> `-3 x^3 - 9 x^4 - 27 x^5`

What's happening here?

Comment: If you use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) to define your functions so that their value is calculated only after the parameters have been assigned their value, you will get the correct answer, i.e. `c[0] == 0`.

Comment: @MarcoB it's not a solution, merely a workaround. I intentionally define my function to symbolic result of `SeriesCoefficient` for arbitrary `n`, not as a delayed call to `SeriesCoefficient` with particular numeric `n`. I could just as easily avoid defining `c[n_]` and instead just copy-paste the output of `SeriesCoefficient`, with the same results.

Comment: Why then would you use `c[n_]`, instead of `c[n]`?

Comment: @JHM erm... how would I pass parameter to the result if I did as you suggest? It'd be as good as `c=...` with usage of `c/.n->...`.

Comment: Well, defining `c[n_]` is the same thing as defining `c[_]`. The parameter wouldn't do anything...

Comment: @JHM `c[n_] = n^2; Print[c[z]]; Clear@c; c[_] = n^2; Print[c[z]];` The two outputs are different.

Comment: Hm, I stand corrected. However, using `Set` to make a function is potentially dangerous. For instance: `n = 2; c[n_] = n^2; c[5]` gives `4`. Any lingering definition of `n` can break the code.

Comment: @JHM that's true. But so is `c[n_]:=abc; c:=3; c[234]`. It's just a matter of knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Your second code is slightly different in nature. Running `n = 2; c[n_] = n^2; c[5]` and `?c` give `c[n_]=4`. i.e. the original definition is lost. But `c[n_]:=abc; c:=3; c[234]` and `?c` give both definition, and the weird result is due to the precedence of `c:=3`. `c[n_]:=abc; n:=3; c[234]` (`SetDelay`ing `n` and not `c`) works.

Comment: @JHM and MarcoB: There's nothing wrong with Set vs SetDelayed. The OP did not make any mistake.  The point is that SeriesCoefficient can compute a general `n`th term, without putting in a number for `n`.  When it does that, it seems that the result is plainly wrong in this case. If you're bothered by the Set/SetDelayed, just don't define any functions and look at the result of `SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, n}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs The problem is that OP wants to define `func[x_]` in a separate line. Also, `c[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, n}]` still has the problem OP has described.

Comment: @JHM Nope, there's absolutely no problem with the definitions, and I don't think there's any point arguing about this. Let me put the question in a different way to you, without using any definitions: `SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, n}] /. n -> 0` and `SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, 0}]` give different results.  Why?  The result from `SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, n}]` looks incorrect.

Comment: @Szabolcs Dang, you're right... Also, one observation: `c[n_] = Re[SeriesCoefficient[func[x], {x, 0, n}]]`  seems to give an approximately correct value for n>=3.

Comment: Did you report this to Wolfram Support?  Let us know what they said.

Comment: @Szabolcs just reported. Their bot answered me with ID of `CASE:3790521`. Will wait for an answer by a human.

Comment: The same wrong behavior in Mathematica 7.0.1, i.e. even earlier than in V.9.0

Comment: @Ruslan This is indeed fixed in 13.3.0 current last version in the cloud. It prints insane result and then prints 0.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников what do you mean by "prints an insane result and then prints 0"? Is the "insane result" equal to 0 after your simplify it, or why are there two outputs?

Comment: @Ruslan c[0] // FullSimplify prints 0, I mean.

Answer (score 6):

A search for `SeriesCoefficient` on this website returns numerous instances of incorrect results, the current question being one.  An often successful workaround is to factor the function into two or more simpler pieces, each of which `SeriesCoefficient` can treat correctly.

```
sc1 = SeriesCoefficient[1/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, n1}];
sc2 = SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x^3], {x, 0, n2}];
c[n_] = Sum[sc1 sc2 /. n1 -> n - n2, {n2, 0, n}]
(* Sum[Piecewise[{{-3^(1 + n - n2), n - n2 >= 0}}, 0]*
       Piecewise[{{((I/2)*(-1)^(n2/6)*(-1 + (-1)^((5*n2)/3)))/(n2/3)!,
           Mod[n2, 3] == 0 && n2 >= 0}}, 0], 
   {n2, 0, n}] *)
```

`c[n]` is the correct expression, although somewhat ungainly.

```
Simplify[Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, 12}] == Series[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, 12}]// Normal]
(* True *)
```

A simpler expression can be obtained from

```
Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[sc1 sc2 /. n1 -> n - n2 /. n2 -> 3 n2, 
    Assumptions -> n2 >= 0 && n2 ∈ Integers], n - 3 n2 >= 0]
(* -((I I^n2 3^(1 + n - 3 n2) (-1 + (-1)^n2))/(2 n2!)) *)

cs[n_] = Sum[%, {n2, 0, Floor[n/3]}]
(* (I 3^(1 + n) E^(-(I/27)) (-Gamma[1 + Floor[n/3], -(I/27)] + 
   E^((2 I)/27) Gamma[1 + Floor[n/3], I/27]))/(2 Gamma[1 + Floor[n/3]]) *)

Simplify[Sum[cs[n] x^n, {n, 0, 12}] == Series[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, 12}]// Normal]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is: Let `SeriesCoefficient` expand around an arbitrary point `a` and then set a to zero. (You get `DifferenceRoot` objects. Working with MMA Version 8.0 ).

```
func[x_] = Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3);
c[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[func[x], {x, a, n}, 
Assumptions -> n >= 0] /. a -> 0 // Simplify

Table[c[n] , {n, 0, 12}]

(*   {0, 0, 0, -3, -9, -27, -81, -243, -729,   
      -(4373/2), -(13119/2), -(39357/2), -(118071/2)}   *)

Simplify[Sum[c[n] x^n, {n, 0, 12}] == 
         Series[Sin[x^3]/(x - 1/3), {x, 0, 12}] // Normal]

(*   True   *)
```